# Could not install package: Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers through Visual Studio

Tags: nuget-package

I want install the package:Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers throungh VS's package manager console, however met the error as below:
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers'At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
 the same status if I want install it by Nuget, could not find this package.Is anything need I do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem since I opened my project in VS 2015.
I think the VS 2015 try to update to a new version, but it's incompatible with the other nugets.

Try on Package Manager Console: PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers -Version 3.0.0